# When I download anything NPM, it downloads but is not accessible from other folders. Only way down in the bin

Tags: npm

I downloaded Flex-cli from share tribe for a project. It finished downloading. If I use basic commands, it doesn't recognize it. It only works if I go down this folder structure. /Users/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/flex-cli. Same thing when I downloaded Vue and some other things. If I run npx Vue or npx flex-cli, it seems to work, but I'd like to fix the problem before it gets worse. Please let me know if you have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

if by saying

> I downloaded Flex-cli

you are referring to `npm install`, then `flex-cli` should be available to you using [`npx flex-cli`](https://github.com/npm/npx)